# Convert librosa-created melspectrogram in png format to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, librosa, spectrogram

Below is the sample python code made by ChatGPT to create melspectrogram by loading a wav audio file and saving it as a png image, with librosa and matplotlib.pyplot. I would like to edit the image and convert it as numpy array and save as a numpy file. My intention is to further load the numpy file as an input to neural vocoder that requires npy-formatted melspectrogram. Thus, the converted file must be equivalent to librosa-generated npy-file
Please educate.

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load audio file
audio_file = 'path/to/audio/file.wav'
y, sr = librosa.load(audio_file, sr=22050)

# Create mel-spectrogram
S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr, n_mels=128, fmax=8000)

# Convert power spectrogram to dB scale (log scale)
S_dB = librosa.power_to_db(S, ref=np.max)

# Plot mel-spectrogram
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
librosa.display.specshow(S_dB, x_axis='time', y_axis='mel', sr=sr, fmax=8000)
plt.title('Mel-Spectrogram')
plt.tight_layout()

# Save as PNG file
plt.savefig('mel-spectrogram.png')
```

Saving S or S_dB as npy is not a solution, because I obtain a modified file as png. Then I would like to convert png as librosa-compatible numpy-format.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `S` and `S_dB` as normal Numpy arrays. You can save them using  [`np.save()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) or [`np.savez()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez).

Pity ChatGPT didn't elaborate.

Comment: Thanks,. But saving S or S_dB as npy is not a solution, because I first obtain a modified png file. Then I would like to convert png as librosa-compatible numpy-format.

Comment: The PNG file in the code is just the `S_dB` array displayed using matplotlib in false color, including a reference color bar, axes, title... which is ok for visualization, but not really useful for post-processing.

Comment: I see. Probably I should not use matplotlib, but something more simple for image processing.